# Trouble passing Bitwarden Secrets in Azure Devops

Tags: npm, azure-devops, yarnpkg

I try to use secrets from Bitwarden Secret Manager in an Azure Devops Pipeline. So I install the Bitwarden SDK, fetch the secrets and set it as env vars, which is all fine. Printing the Token variable shows me the correct value. Unfortunately, yarn gets an 401 - unauthorized for font awesome access.

```
- job: lint
    displayName: 'Test Code Style'
    steps:
      - checkout: self
      
      - task: AzureKeyVault@2
        inputs:
            azureSubscription: $(azureServiceConnection)
            keyVaultName: $(azureVaultName)
            secretsFilter: 'BitwardenAccessToken'
        displayName: 'Azure Key Vault: Get BW Access Token'

      - script: |
          sudo apt-get install -y jq
          latest_release=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/bitwarden/sdk/releases/latest)
          download_url=$(echo "$latest_release" | jq -r '.assets[] | select(.name | endswith(".zip") and contains("linux")) | .browser_download_url')
          curl -L -o bws.zip "$download_url"
          unzip bws.zip
          chmod +x bws
          sudo mv bws /usr/local/bin/
          BWS_SERVER_URL="https://vault.bitwarden.eu" 
          BWS_ACCESS_TOKEN="$(BitwardenAccessToken)"
          GITHUB_TOKEN="$(bws secret get *** --access-token $BWS_ACCESS_TOKEN --server-url $BWS_SERVER_URL | jq -r '.value')"
          FONT_AWESOME_TOKEN="$(bws secret get *** --access-token $BWS_ACCESS_TOKEN --server-url $BWS_SERVER_URL | jq -r '.value')"
          echo $FONT_AWESOME_TOKEN | sed 's/./& /g'
        displayName: 'Install Bitwarden SDK and set Secrets as Environment Variables'

      - task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '16.x'
        displayName: 'Install Node.js'

      - script: |
          npm config set "@stackmeistergmbh:registry" "https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
          npm config set "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken" "$GITHUB_TOKEN"
          npm config set "//npm.pkg.github.com/:always-auth" "true"
          npm config set "@fortawesome:registry" "https://npm.fontawesome.com/" 
          npm config set "//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken" "$FONT_AWESOME_TOKEN"
          npm config set "//npm.fontawesome.com/:always-auth" "true" 
          yarn 
        displayName: 'Authenticate in NPM registries and install dependencies'
```

I did try to fetch all the secrets via Azure Key Vault, which works perfectly fine for yarn. I checked and the resulting token value is the same with Azure KV and with Bitwarden. So I guess the pass to npm config is the problem somehow?